# Query large table with 50 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

trying to query a large table (senddb.order_histories) that has close to 50M rows and this is the MySQL query I am using:

> FIRST APPROACH- inner join:

```
select a.id, 
    a.order_number, 
    a.sku_id,
    a.fulfillment_status, 
    a.modified_by, 
    a.created_at, 
    a.updated_at 
from senddb.order_line_items a
inner join (
    select order_line_item_id, 
    order_number, 
    order_status, 
    order_status_description, 
    action, 
    modified_by, 
    created_at, 
    max(updated_at) as updated_at
from senddb.order_histories 
where order_status in ('x','y','z')
and fulfillment_location = 'abcd'
group by order_line_item_id) as b
on a.id = b.order_line_item_id
and a.fulfillment_status = '2';
```

> EXPLAIN output :

[image]

> SECOND APPROACH- nested select:

```
select a.id, 
    a.order_number, 
    a.sku_id,
    a.fulfillment_status, 
    a.modified_by, 
    a.created_at, 
    a.updated_at 
from senddb.order_line_items a
where a.fulfillment_status = '2'
and a.id in (
select b.order_line_item_id from(
select order_line_item_id, 
    order_number, 
    order_status, 
    order_status_description, 
    action, 
    modified_by, 
    created_at, 
    max(updated_at) as updated_at
from senddb.order_histories 
where
order_status in ('x','y','z')
and fulfillment_location = 'abcd'
group by order_line_item_id) as b);
```

I believe nested select is a bad approach on large data but i anyhow added it here because it worked on my sample set. Anyway both the queries eventually time out after 600 seconds with the message : Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query.

I would like to know if there are any ways to alter the query to make it run faster. I have already tried reducing the columns in the inner select / inner join but that should not really be an issue IMO. I also looked up a solution that says "create a clustered index" but i wasn't really able to follow. Any help is appreciated.

> TABLE order_histories :

```
order_histories CREATE TABLE `order_histories` (
`id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`order_number` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_status_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`datetime_stamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`action` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`fulfillment_location` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_status` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modified_by` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_line_item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`pooled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `order_histories_ecash_idx` (`order_number`),
 KEY `order_line_item_id` (`order_line_item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=454738178 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> TABLE order_line_items :

```
order_line_items CREATE TABLE `order_line_items` (
`id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`order_number` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
`sku_id` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`original_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
`dept_description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`quantity_ordered` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`gift_indicator` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`gift_wrap_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`shipping_record_flag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`gift_comments` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`item_status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`tax_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
`tax_rate` float DEFAULT NULL,
`upc` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`final_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
`line_number` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`master_line_number` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`gift_wrap_flag_type` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`color_code` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`size_id` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`width_id` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`brand` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`vpn` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`dept_number` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`class_number` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`non_merch_item` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modified_by` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`chain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fulfillment_location` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fulfillment_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`fulfillment_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fulfillment_sales_associate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`gift_wrap_line_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`shipping_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`order_track_info_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`store_tlog_updated` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`shipping_tlx_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`store_closed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`flags` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`deal_based_index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_calc_ret_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_retail_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_ext_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_flag_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_flag_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tlog_flag_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`time_remaining` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `order_line_items_ecash_idx` (`order_number`),
KEY `order_line_item_fulfillment_location_idx` (`fulfillment_location`),
KEY `order_line_item_fulfillment_status_idx` (`fulfillment_status`),
KEY `upc_idx` (`upc`),
KEY `sku_id_idx` (`sku_id`),
KEY `order_line_items_idx001` (`order_number`,`id`,`fulfillment_status`),
KEY `order_track_info_id` (`order_track_info_id`),
KEY `shipping_type_idx` (`shipping_type`,`non_merch_item`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11367052 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can I ask whats your purpose of selecting 50M records? first add limit and select limited number of records then join it with secondary table

Comment: I am trying to select all the IDs from table B (the large table) with a certain where condition and pull the corresponding data for those IDs from table A.

Comment: Indexes. I do these with that sizing no problemo.

Comment: So plop the word EXPLAIN in front of either query and run it. It will take a few seconds max for either. Publish those results and the schemas of all relevant tables.

Comment: For this question in it's present form, all answers will be a case of the blind leading the blind. Please post the explain output as suggested by @drew + add your table structure with indexes

Comment: until you get the output of that, schema meaning the output of `show create table myTableXYZ` for every table relevant, it is all nonsense. And why most questions on the stack like this take 2 hours or sit and rot.

Comment: @Drew added both the table structures..

Comment: And the `Explain` output

Comment: @Drew added the explain output too for the inner join query.

Comment: Alright, I alerted them below. Let me know in a while if you need me to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query can be simplified:

```
select a.id, 
    a.order_number, 
    a.sku_id,
    a.fulfillment_status, 
    a.modified_by, 
    a.created_at, 
    a.updated_at 
from senddb.order_line_items a
inner join senddb.order_histories b on a.id = b.order_line_item_id
where b.order_status in ('x','y','z')
and b.fulfillment_location = 'abcd'    
and a.fulfillment_status = '2';
```

Since you're only selecting values from table `a`, you don't need to select specific values from table `b` and can instead just apply your conditions.  Outside of this, you need to ensure that `b.order_line_item_id` has an index on it.  You can find more about creating indexes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).  I'm not an expert in MySQL but something similar to this should work if `senddb.order_histories.order_line_item_id` isn't already the primary key.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_order_histories_order_line_item_id ON order_histories (order_line_item_id);
```

Comment: @Nick i tried this simplified query and it works ! trying to validate if it did pull the desired data. avoiding the "group by" that i used in the inner select might have made the query faster as well. I have a question though.. so what if i selected those specific values from table B? that should ideally not have a huge impact on the performance right?

Comment: Start by trying it out and if it's too slow when you add it, that's a good next question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up the [optimization section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization.html) of the MySQL docs. It contains a lot of information on how you can optimize your queries and data sets. The main idea here is to add indexes to the fields that are being used as the criteria in the WHERE clause of the SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, *both* of your alternatives are using a "sub-`SELECT`, *not* an `INNER JOIN`.

The syntax of a true `JOIN` is one of the following:

```
SELECT ...
FROM X INNER JOIN Y USING (field_list)
```

... or ...

```
SELECT ...
FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON (x.field1 = y.field2) ...
```

But in both cases the objects being joined are *tables* or *views.*

I'm going to presume ... admittedly, without checking ...  that Nick Larsen's answer #1 adequately re-expresses your original query using `JOINs`.

(Notice how, in his answer, the shorthand identifiers `A` and `B` are introduced as referring to each of the two table-names mentioned in his query.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to decide if a 50 million resultset is what you are asking for. Big data tables are not there so that you can select all their rows. They are there so that you can ask them questions using sql queries. SQL is a query language, it's not a data loading language.

What's your purpose? If you want to copy the data you can do that by loading the data, for example, 1000 rows per query in a for loop. if you are loading the data for processing, you can do that in the same way.

If you want to derive statistical information, you can use outer join and return a low number of rows, using aggregate functions. But you shouldn't do that either, what you "should" do is to decide what you want from the table and preferably, run aggregate functions to store useful information in a different table. (mostly SELECT INTO queries) You should never need to join a table of 50 million records in the first place.

Telling you how to do something wrong using indexes wouldn't be the right thing here.

Comment: my purpose is to basically do a cleanup : cleanup/update accordingly ALL the orders in table A (order_line_items) if they have a history of being already cancelled in table B (order_histories).

Comment: @Maha_Balu2705 there is no basic way to  do a cleanup. What kind of info do you want to extract from the database?

Comment: This frankly sounds to me like something that should be done by a small *script* or *program.* A **correctly written** `inner join` query should provide the result-set that you need to make the determination of which orders need to be modified, but this query probably will **not** be directly updatable. Instead, you will issue other queries given an order-id. And, you probably want to do it using a well thought-out system of SQL `transaction`s. And, so on.

Comment: (Also, such a program can more-easily process *segments* of the database, by issuing multiple queries that "touch" fewer rows at a time. Business-rules logic can be readily implemented.)

Comment: your query is more likely to be like - delete from table a where exists (select * from table b where b.somecolumn=a.somecolumn) . for safety you can create a column of bit type and mark them for deletion using an update set query in a similar way. and then run a delete query on the records you marked for deletion